# Cant access variable inside .catch(function(error) Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Trying to toast erros but i cant access the toast variable from the construtor is says that is undefined, and i cant see why. What im doing wrong here ? in other classes it works just fine, witch is weird. The error 
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toastCtrl' of undefined". any help would be great

```
//Imports

import {
    Component,
    ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    NavController,
    NavParams,
    Platform,
    ToastController
} from 'ionic-angular';


import {
    Keyboard
} from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

import {
    Storage
} from '@ionic/storage';
import {
    fireUser
} from './../../objects/firebaseStructures';

import {
    MySegService
} from './../../services/myseg-api.service';



//Component

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {

    // Login details
    email: string;
    emailTest: string;
    loggedUser: fireUser;
    password: string;
    passwordTest: string;
    responseMessage: string;
    success: boolean = false;
    uid: string;
    user: string;
    registerUserPage = RegisterUserPage;
    forgetpass = ForgetPasswordPage;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public mysegService: MySegService, private platform: Platform,
        private keyboard: Keyboard, private storage: Storage, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {

        this.loggedUser = new fireUser(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); //user initialization
    }

    signInUser() {
        var user2: string;
        this.mysegService.loginUser(this.email, this.password).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                //unsuccessful log in
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                        message: 'wrong password',
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: 'top'
                    });

                    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
                        console.log('Dismissed toast');
                    });

                    toast.present();
                } else {
                    // alert(errorMessage);
                }
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

}
```

Comment: Change `.catch(function (error) {` to `.catch((error) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function `=>` instead of normal function callback.

Your code should be -

```
signInUser() {
        var user2: string;
        this.mysegService.loginUser(this.email, this.password).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                .......
            });

    }
```